# Navigating to ScienceDirect's NextPage using scrapy

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, scrapy

Using Scrapy, how to navigate to "nextpage" link, from any results page generate by [sciencedirect.com](http://www.sciencedirect.com)?

The nextpage link is the input element:

```
<div class="paginationBar">
<span style="color:#A4A4A4;" aria-disabled="true" alt="Previous Page" title="Previous Page"><< Previous</span>
<span class="pageText">Page 1 of 20462</span>
<input class="nextPrev" type="submit" title="Next Page" alt="Next Page" name="bottomNext" onmouseout="this. className='nextPrev'" onmouseover="this.className='nextPrevHov'" value="Next >>">
</div>
```

And exists some javascript but I dont know how to take it :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: there is no JavaScript involved.

If you look at the site you can see, that the link `Next >>` is an `input` field which `submit`s the `form`.

When looking at the `form` itself, you can see, that it sends a `get` request to a site. The `input` fields to this request you can gather together and then `yield` a new `Request` with Scrapy to scrape the next site.

An example would be:

```
form = response.xpath('//form[@name="Tag"]')[0]
url = 'http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/?'
for inp in form.xpath('.//input[@type="hidden"]'):
    url += inp.xpath('./@name').extract()[0]+'='+inp.xpath('./@value').extract()[0]+'&'
url += 'bottomNext=Next+%3E%3E&resultsPerPage=25'
yield Request(url)
```

Naturally some error handling is needed (for example after 1000 results you cannot view more so you will get an error site which does not have the `form`).